# SQL select all ID's into temp table according to comma delimited string

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structured as such:

```html
|  ID  |  Name  |
|  1   |  Bob   |
|  2   |  Jim   |
|  3   |  Jane  |
   .       .
   .       .
   .       .
```

I am trying to compose a query that will return all ID's of the names that I will be passing. Note that the names will be passed as a comma delimited string.

The query i've tried is:

`@Names = 'Bob, Jane'`

`select ID into #Ids from Users where Name in ((select i.Item from dbo.Split(@Names, ',', 0) as i))`

What I was hoping to get was:

```html
|  ID  |
|  1   | 
|  3   |
```

but instead I just get:

```html
|  ID  |
|  1   |
```

I would have to loop through this query, but what is the best way to do so? Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Comment: What does _select i.Item from dbo.Split(@Names, ',', 0) as i)_ return?

Comment: @jpw returns the string 'Bob, Jane' as a table. Row[0] = Bob, Row[1] = Jane etc.

Comment: could you try to remove the double parenthesis in `((select i.Item from dbo.Split(@Names, ',', 0) as i))`

Comment: Are you sure the Split function is trimming off the space after the comma? What is the third parameter of the Split function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the trailing spaces in the output of `split function`.

After comma you have a space. It should be removed because in SQL Server only `=` operator ignores trailing spaces when making the comparison. Use `Ltrim` and `Rtrim` functions to remove the trailing spaces before making comparison

```
SELECT ID
INTO   #Ids
FROM   Users
WHERE  NAME IN ((SELECT rtrim(ltrim(i.Item))
                 FROM   dbo.Split(@Names, ',', 0) AS i))
```